# Elastic search issue with mapping in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

versions used:

Spring Data Elasticsearch = 5.0.1

Elasticsearch = 8.5.3

Spring Boot = 3.0.5

ElasticProduct Doc type:

```
@Setting(settingPath = "product-settings.json")
public class ElasticProduct {
    @Id
    @Field
    public String id;
    @Field
    public String productId;
    @Field
    public String productName;
    @Field
    public String productCategory1;
    @Field
    public String productCategory2;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    public List<ElasticProductVariant> productVariantList;

}

public class ElasticProductVariant {
    public String productVariantId;
    public String productVariantName;
    public String productBrand;
}
```

elastic Mapping: product-settings.json

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        },
        "edgeNGram_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "side": "front"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "edge_nGram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "english_stop",
            "english_stemmer",
            "edgeNGram_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "20",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "productName": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "productDescription": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "productCategory1": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "productCategory2": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "productVariantList": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "productBrand": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Getting below error for above setup:

[es/indices.create] failed: [illegal_argument_exception] unknown setting [index.mappings.properties.productCategory2.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings

Comment: where does this mapping come from? When does the error occur?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch
trace:
"name": "co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException",
                "extendedStackTrace": [
                  {
                    "class": "co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport",
                    "method": "getHighLevelResponse",
                    "file": "RestClientTransport.java",
                    "line": 282,
                    "exact": false,
                    "location": "elasticsearch-java-8.5.3.jar",
                    "version": "?"
                  }

Comment: exception: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException

Comment: when I am trying directly via curl elastic is able to create this index with the same mappings. 

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT localhost:9200/product --data-binary @product-settings.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Setting` annotation is to provide the settings for the index, not the mapping. You pass in the mapping as part of the settings by adding it there - and your settings from the file would en up under "settings.settings".

Split your file into the part that contains the setting and one that contains the mapping and pass these in with the `@Setting` and `@Mapping` annotation. As an alternative, for the mappping you can define the values with the corresponding annotations on the properties of the entity class.